# ReSharper Auto Closes Variable in NAnt

Tags: resharper, nant

When I edit my NAnt scripts for some reason ReSharper always enters the closing brace when I type ${ so I get ${}. Any ideas on how to turn this off?

I have tried disabling the ReSharper setting for Auto-insert closing brace in the Editor settings.

Comment: ReSharper 6 does not have this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`CTRL + 8` will disable ( toggle ) Resharper on current file. I don't think there is any other option to do what you want alone.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have productivity power tools installed? I did and was having the same problem... You can disable this in the productivity power tools options.

Edit: nevermind, that worked for some reason until I closed the file...